# Any reasonable way to sort DynamoDB tables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using spring-data-dynamodb 5.1.0 in my Spring Boot 2.5.4 setup.  I am trying to get this sample code to work for sorting on `SongTitle` column on which I have defined a global secondary index.
Here's my entity object.`public class ImprovedMusic {

```
@Id
private ImprovedMusicId improvedMusicId;

public ImprovedMusic() {}

public ImprovedMusic(ImprovedMusicId improvedMusicId) {
    this.improvedMusicId = improvedMusicId;
}

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Artist")
public String getArtist() {
    return improvedMusicId != null ? improvedMusicId.getArtist() : null;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    if (improvedMusicId == null) {
        improvedMusicId = new ImprovedMusicId();
    }
    improvedMusicId.setArtist(artist);
}

@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "SongTitle", globalSecondaryIndexNames={"GSISongTitle"})
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName="SongTitle", globalSecondaryIndexNames = "GSISongTitle")
public String getSongTitle() {
    return improvedMusicId != null ? improvedMusicId.getSongTitle() : null;
}

public void setSongTitle(String songTitle) {
    if (improvedMusicId == null) {
        improvedMusicId = new ImprovedMusicId();
    }
    improvedMusicId.setSongTitle(songTitle);
}
```

}
`
I invoke this code in my test

```
`Sort sortBy =  Sort.by("SongTitle").descending;
 Pageable page = PageRequest.of(1,5,sortBy);
 Page aPage = myRepositor.findAll(page);`
```

Please note,  I am not trying to search by `SongTitle`, I want this list to be sorted by the songtitle. The above test throws the following exception. Anything I am doing wrong here?

> The number of conditions on the keys is invalid (Service:
> AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
> Request ID: c0634958-d465-4560-8dce-3e51519b4ed6)
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The
> number of conditions on the keys is invalid (Service:
> AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
> Request ID: c0634958-d465-4560-8dce-3e51519b4ed6) at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1

Comment: What are the partition key and sort key on the GSI? From the code sample you provided it looks like you have the SongTitle as both. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct @Kirk. Not sure if (and how) I can indicate my partition key should be the Id.

Comment: What I do not understand yet is what you are trying to do exactly. Can you write down what the access pattern? e.g. "Get a Artist and all their songs, sorted alphabetically by SongTitle" or something like that.

Comment: You said it. Idea is to be able to sort randomly with various attributes in future starting with SongTitle for now. This is an example I am working from the Medium, not the specific code from my project but this is the idea.

Comment: Then the artist needs to be the partition key and the song the sort key. That would satisfy that access pattern.

Comment: Be mindful of the requirement to "sort randomly with various attributes".  DynamoDB isn't a great search solution for ad-hoc searching/sorting.  However, it's a *great* tool if the number of attributes you want to sort are known up-front.

Also, if your data set is small enough, don't discount sorting/searching on the client-side.  You could use DDB to fetch by artist, then sort any way you like in the client application.  Best of both worlds!

Comment: I am going with the `SongTitle` as the sort key @Kirk, but I run into this error  "The number of conditions on the keys is invalid (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;" If I provide a title, just for the heck of it, it then throws the error "Sorting not supported on scan expressions". Driving me nuts. How do I query, with the choice of partition key and sort key?

Comment: Gaaah. I just had to run `findAll()` and it would come back sorted by the range key. Mea culpa. Thank you for the education @Kirk, and @Seth Geoghegan, we hope to have the range attributes under control, thanks for the warning!

Comment: But what happens when I define multiple `@DynamoDBRangeKey`s and a single Partition key btw?

Comment: You can only have one range key per table/index.